# 'ModuleNotFoundError' when trying to import module from imported package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

This is my directory structure:

```
man/                          
  Mans/                  
          man1.py
  MansTest/
          SoftLib/
                  Soft/
                      SoftWork/
                              manModules.py
          Unittests/
                    man1test.py
```

`man1.py` contains the following *import* statement, **which I do not want to change**:

```
from Soft.SoftWork.manModules import *
```

`man1test.py` contains the following *import* statements:

```
from ...MansTest.SoftLib import Soft
from ...Mans import man1
```

I need the second *import* in `man1test.py` because `man1test.py` needs access to a function in `man1.py`.

My rationale behind the first import (*Soft*) was to facilitate the aforementioned *import* statement in `man1.py`.

Contrary to my expectation, however, the *import* statement in `man1.py` gives rise to:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Soft'
```

when I run

```
python3 -m man.MansTest.Unittests.man1test
```

from a directory above *man/*.

Is there any way to resolve this error without changing the *import* statement in `man1.py` **and** without adding anything to *sys.path*?

Edit: `python3 -m man.ManTest.Unittests.man1test` from the original version of the question changed to `python3 -m man.MansTest.Unittests.man1test`

Comment: You can hack `__path__` of imported modules. It's not `sys.path` but is it OK for you?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

**FIRST**, if you want to be able to access *man1.py* from *man1test.py* AND *manModules.py* from *man1.py*, you need to properly setup your files as [packages and modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

> Packages are a way of structuring Python’s module namespace by using
> “dotted module names”. For example, the module name `A.B` designates a
> submodule named `B` in a package named `A`.
>
> ...
>
> When importing the package, Python searches through the directories on
> `sys.path` looking for the package subdirectory.
>
> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the
> directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent
> directories with a common name, such as `string`, from unintentionally
> hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path.

You need to set it up to something like this:

```
man
|- __init__.py
|- Mans
   |- __init__.py
   |- man1.py
|- MansTest
   |- __init__.py
   |- SoftLib
      |- Soft
         |- __init__.py
         |- SoftWork
            |- __init__.py
            |- manModules.py
      |- Unittests
         |- __init__.py
         |- man1test.py
```

**SECOND**, for the "`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Soft'`" error caused by `from ...Mans import man1` in *man1test.py*, the documented solution to that is to add *man1.py* to `sys.path` since *Mans* is outside the *MansTest* package. See [The Module Search Path](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) from the Python documentation. But if you don't want to modify `sys.path` directly, you can also modify `PYTHONPATH`:

> `sys.path` is initialized from these locations:
>
> - The directory containing the input script (or the current directory when no file is specified).
> - `PYTHONPATH` (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable `PATH`).
> - The installation-dependent default.

**THIRD**, for `from ...MansTest.SoftLib import Soft` which you said "*was to facilitate the aforementioned import statement in man1.py*", that's now how imports work. If you want to import *Soft.SoftLib* in *man1.py*, you have to setup *man1.py* to find *Soft.SoftLib* and import it there directly.

With that said, here's how I got it to work.

man1.py:

```
from Soft.SoftWork.manModules import *
# no change to import statement but need to add Soft to PYTHONPATH

def foo():
    print("called foo in man1.py")
    print("foo call module1 from manModules: " + module1())
```

man1test.py

```
# no need for "from ...MansTest.SoftLib import Soft" to facilitate importing..
from ...Mans import man1

man1.foo()
```

manModules.py

```
def module1():
    return "module1 in manModules"
```

Terminal output:

```
$ python3 -m man.MansTest.Unittests.man1test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
    from ...Mans import man1
  File "/temp/man/Mans/man1.py", line 2, in <module>
    from Soft.SoftWork.manModules import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Soft'

$ PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/temp/man/MansTest/SoftLib
$ export PYTHONPATH
$ echo $PYTHONPATH
:/temp/man/MansTest/SoftLib
$ python3 -m man.MansTest.Unittests.man1test
called foo in man1.py
foo called module1 from manModules: module1 in manModules
```

---

As a suggestion, maybe re-think the purpose of those *SoftLib* files. Is it some sort of "bridge" between *man1.py* and *man1test.py*? The way your files are setup right now, I don't think it's going to work as you expect it to be. Also, it's a bit confusing for the code-under-test (*man1.py*) to be importing stuff from under the test folder (*MansTest*).

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer. I am currently busy with a different project and haven't had time to implement your solution, which is why I haven't marked the answer as "accepted" yet. I did upvote it, but it's not going to show because I am new here and have less than 15 reputations.

In any case, in reference to how you got it to work, is there an alternative to modifying PYTHONPATH? I want to solve this problem without modifying any "path" so the code can be transported as it is and used by others without making any modification to their "paths". Thanks again!

Comment: @strangeloop Hmm.. I don't think there is any other way. If you read the Python docs for the [the Module Search Path](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path), that's how the interpreter finds the files you `import`. If you want to make the code portable and avoid others doing extra steps, you can modify `sys.path` internally inside *man1test.py*, **before** you import *man1.py*. The path modification will only take effect until your program is running, it's not going to affect your user's env. The user just needs to make sure the folders are copied correctly.

Comment: Is there any reason why, in your example module structure, `|- Soft` has an |- __init__.py' but `|- SoftLib` does not?

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem, although not the same.

My folders and files had the structure (GUI_ML is the main folder):

```
GUI_ML
\ Views \ login.py
\ Views \ __ init __.py
\ Controllers \ Control_login.py
\ Controllers \ __ init __.py
```

I needed to import Control_login.py from login.py. The following code solved my problem:

```
import sys
import os
myDir = os.getcwd()
sys.path.append(myDir)

from pathlib import Path
path = Path(myDir)
a=str(path.parent.absolute())

sys.path.append(a)

from Controllers.Control_login import Control_login
```

Answer (score 3):

For me when I created a file and saved it as python file, I was getting this error during importing.
I had to create a filename with the type ".py" , like  filename.py and then save it as a python file.
post trying to import the file worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

some package name and module name might be the same. this conflict is also responded with this error.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue where I forgot to put a `__init__.py` in the module and spend a lot of time wasting trying to understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution depends on where you run this code from.

Assuming the OP's directory structure:

```
man/                          
  Mans/                  
          man1.py
  MansTest/
          SoftLib/
                  Soft/
                      SoftWork/
                              manModules.py
          Unittests/
                    man1test.py
```

If you try running `python Mans/man1.py` (from the man directory), you would have to do the following two things for this to work:

1. Change the import line in man1.py to `from ManTest.SoftLib.Soft.SoftWork.manModules import *`
2. If not already there, add to your system environment variable. Key `PYTHONPATH`, value `.`