# Getting a ModuleNotFoundError when trying to load a Python Module and all seems ok

Tags: python-3.x, python-module

I have a tree structure

```
 - My_app    
   - __init__.py
   - main.py
   - Cus_Scripts  
      - __init__.py
      - script1.py
      - script2.py - classA
```

I am running like this

- main.py has import Cus_Scripts.script1
- script1.py has from script2 import classA

in script1 I get a ModuleNotFoundError saying it can't find script2.  I am using VSC.

Comment: It's `__init__.py`. You have missed underscores

Comment: @bigbounty it already is. Markdown syntax makes it bold.

Comment: Have you seen this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54598292/python-modulenotfounderror-when-trying-to-import-module-from-imported-package/54613085

Comment: @MeirGabay i am not looking to go back up.  I have main script which calls script1 and then script1 is calling into script2.  main doesn't call into script2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by adding this to every file.

```
#Custom Lib
sys.path.insert(1, os.getcwd())
```

This allowed me to access anypart of the program with

```
from My_App.script2 import classA
import My_App.script1
```

Comment: So eventually you did go back up :)