# Import my own added module/library but gives a not found error

Tags: python, lib

Working on MacOS with Python 3.9. I am a very new with python.

I did create some Lib's that are specific to my needs and want them place at the right place so I could use them in my play, snippets, work and final folders.
If I use

```
python3.9 -m site
sys.path
= [
    '/Volumes/Data/Users/LA',
    '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python39.zip',
    '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9',
    '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
    '/Volumes/Data/Users/LA/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages', 
    '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages',
]
```

I get my python3.9 user_base and user_site folder and did place my Libs in there.
Inside '/Volumes/Data/Users/LA/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages'

However if I import them like I did when they where in the same folder as my application code I get the error that it can't be found.

What do I wrong? I did kill all the Python processes in the hope it will load everything, but after that everything is still the same. I can import when I use the old way, but using the user sitepackages folder it is not.

```
>>> import importlib
>>> import sys
>>> importlib.reload(sys.modules['myGenericLib'])


from myGenericLib import reload
```

and more doesn't work.

What could be the solution?
Thank you

Comment: Probably it's an error with your project tree. Maybe duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54598292/python-modulenotfounderror-when-trying-to-import-module-from-imported-package/54613085)

Comment: I did do this and again again. A NoGo. The only thing is that if I use the PYTHONPATH and add my path in there it works when I am in debug mode but not in the terminal. For now I did give up and created from where the modules are a softlink to the same folder where my main script lives.