# Import local package from local script

Tags: python

I am having this project structure:

```
.
├── README.md
├── my_project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── integrations
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── google_places.py
├── requirements.txt
└── scripts
    └── my_script.py
```

In `my_script.py` I have:

```
from my_project.integrations.google_places import GooglePlaces
```

However I get the following error when running `python scripts/my_script.py`:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_project'
```

Locally I can `pip install -e .` my package (by adding a `setup.py` to the mix), however since I need to run this from GitHub Actions it feels it doesn't make sense to pursue the same avenue.

I've been reading about manipulating `sys.path`, but it seems a bit hackish.

Since this is a fairly common setup (I guess), what's the recommended way of fixing the above error? I can alter the project structure if it would make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This also surprised me, but after reading this pretty comprehensive answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54613085/6180150, and into the linked python docs about the [module search path](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) in python, I think you have to adjust the `PYTHONPATH`. The problem is that the two python files reside in two separate packages, namely `scripts` and `my_project`, so `my_script.py` is not able to find the `google_places.py`, because the `PYTHONPATH` only contains the current package and not the parent folder and python will only search following directories (see the aforementioned search path docs):

> - The directory containing the input script (or the current directory when no file is specified).
> - PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
> - The installation-dependent default.

Also in this comment: [Python: 'ModuleNotFoundError' when trying to import module from imported package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54598292/python-modulenotfounderror-when-trying-to-import-module-from-imported-package/54613085#comment96151275_54613085) the replier of above answer explains nicely that adjusting the `PYTHONPATH` is not really a hacky solution (although I would have also felt so), but the documented solution according to python, too.

If possible, in case I were in your shoes, I think I would move the `my_script.py` into the `my_project` package, like follows.

```
.
├── README.md
├── my_project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── integrations
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── google_places.py
│   └── my_script.py
└── requirements.txt
```

Then you can adapt your import to:

```
from integrations.google_places import GooglePlaces
```

---

EDIT:

If you like to use the following file tree structure (or even the original should work).

```
.
├── README.md
├── my_project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── integrations
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── google_places.py
│   └── scripts
│       └── my_script.py
└── requirements.txt
```

You can just modify your sys.path like this and then use the original import statement:

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd())
from my_project.integrations.google_places import GooglePlaces
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I mention that `scripts` is not a package, since it doesn't contain any `__init__.py` file. But, I have moved `scripts` under `my_project`, made it a package, updated the import as per your suggestion and ran the scripts with `python my_project/scripts/my_script.py`, however it failed with: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'integrations'`

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, because python will again search according to its search model: "The directory containing the input script (or the current directory when no file is specified)". Meaning it looks inside `my_project/scripts/` and the `PYTHONPATH`. If you need to keep it under `scripts`, you should update the `sys.path`.

Comment: @linkyndy I just added another sample code, which adapts the `sys.path`, so you can import the module successfully. It should also allow to use the original file tree structure. Let me know if it works :)

Comment: I ended up moving all scripts on the top level, no more nesting under `scripts`. Thanks for assisting into this!

Comment: That's what I would've also done. Feels less hacky :D