# Django - Databases

Tags: django, django-models

I have two projects in django, proj1 and proj2,

Aim - I want to use common database(postgresql) between proj1 and proj2.

Problem - proj1 has all the models,  How do I import models in proj2?

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: If your projects share models why not have both projects import the models from a shared app/package?

Comment: simplest way use linux soft link `ln -s source target`.

Comment: Iain Shelvington, can you explain in more simpler words? Proj1 have all the models. And I want to use those models in Proj2.

Comment: nay, I don't use Linux. I use Windows.

Comment: @Abhinavverma Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54613085/9006675

Comment: @ariaman5 I am not understanding what that answer means

Comment: @Abhinavverma you wanted to import models which is in a differenct project with a different directory, hence i gave that reference.