# Module importing works in python console (pycharm) but not works on terminal

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

Hi i'm recently working on a module in python (package named pykiwoom)

I installed a module in conda 32-bit environment `pip install pykiwoom` and tried to import this

```
from pykiwoom.kiwoom import Kiwoom
```

This works perfectly fine when I execute this in python console in pycharm

However, when I try this in terminal error occurs

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pykiwoom.kiwoom'; 'pykiwoom' is not a package`

internal structure of package pykiwoom looks like this

pykiwoom

- **init**.py
- kiwoom.py
- parser.py

Can somebody tell me why this error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

I think where you install your package is important in your case. You can check the packages installed using `pip list` in terminal, and check if you find it there.
This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54598292/python-modulenotfounderror-when-trying-to-import-module-from-imported-package/54613085) provides overview of how to setup your files as packages and modules.
Nevertheless, I think if you install your package in the terminal using pip, you could possibly access it.