# Module not found error in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, relative-import

At design time and using autocomplete, I can add the line `from myitems import CarItem`.

However, when I run my spider `scrapy crawl keizer -o allobjects.json`,

I get error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myitems'

Output:

```
  File "C:\scrapy\hw_spiders\spiders\keizer.py", line 11, in <module>
    from myitems import CarItem
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myitems'
```

My folder structure:

[image]

My files:

**keizer.py**

```
import json
import re
import os

import scrapy
import time
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

from myitems import CarItem
```

Not sure if it's relevant, I also added this to ".vscode\settings.json" file:

```
{
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "./hw_spiders"
    ]
}
```

I already checked here and read about relative imports, but I don't know how to map the proposed solutions to my current project structure as they're quite different. If my project structure is wrong or not recommended, I'd love to hear that too.

- [Relative imports - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43728431/relative-imports-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-x)
- [Python: 'ModuleNotFoundError' when trying to import module from imported package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54598292/python-modulenotfounderror-when-trying-to-import-module-from-imported-package/54613085)

## Another attempt

I changed `from myitems import CarItem` to `from .myitems import CarItem`.
I immediately see a design time error:

> Import ".myitems" could not be resolved (PylancereportMissingImports)

But I ran the spider anyway.

When I run `C:\scrapy\hw_spiders> scrapy crawl keizer -o allobjects.json`, I get:

> File "C:\scrapy\hw_spiders\spiders\keizer.py", line 11, in 
> from .myitems import CarItem
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hw_spiders.spiders.myitems'

When I run `C:\scrapy> scrapy crawl keizer -o allobjects.json`, I get:

> File "C:\scrapy\hw_spiders\spiders\keizer.py", line 11, in 
> from .myitems import CarItem
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hw_spiders.spiders.myitems'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `myitems` folder is in the same `directory` folder, Then try as follows:

```
from ..myitems import CarItem
```

Comment: Hi Fazlul. When I add your answer and then debug it, I get the following error: `runspider: error: Unable to load 'c:\\scrapy\\hw_spiders\\spiders\\keizer.py': attempted relative import with no known parent package` Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Hi@ Adam, It's hard to guess without full scrapy project. When you will use project then you have to use  meaning you have to use project and terminal run command is as follows: scrapy crawl name of your spider, this is my present thinking. Thanks

Comment: Hi Fazlull. When I run `scrapy crawl <spidername> -o allobjects.json` I get error `twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable`
When I debug and step through I get the mentioned error after all spider code has been executed. My full project is here https://file.io/MTKJEckHgoal (password `Fazlul`), if you're willing and have time to take a look :)

Comment: Hi@ Adam, scrapy project meaning   hw_spiders  and BOT_NAME = 'hw'   in settings.file aren't the same. They must be the same meaning   hw_spiders  and BOT_NAME = 'hw'_spiders.  And it may remain more errors. After 2-3 days I will free to deeply analize it. Create new project and debug, don't override any scrapy project files

Comment: and gain  more knowledge  from online only for scrapy project portion

Comment: The weird thing is that other spiders in that same project do function correctly, I can't however share those due to privacy, so it's something with the one I included it the project I shared. I massively appreciate any and all help! :)

Comment: Hi Fazlul, any chance you had some time to look at my project :) O:)

Comment: Hi Adam. I'm sorry for nothing can do on it. It would be better to create a new post more focus on it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I just started a new thread with some more details, please check here if you like :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69975014/scrap-splash-crawler-reactornotrestartable

Answer (score -1):

[Scrapy](https://pypi.org/project/Scrapy/) should be installed in your current used python environment.

Open an **integrated Terminal** and run

```
pip show scrapy
```

Check if its location is `current environment\lib\site-packages.`

If not, please reinstall it by running `pip install scrapy`.